How to describe with words, the diagrams containing fused heads?
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 412:



It's easy to say what the NP is here: the NP is "few of her friends".
But how to describe with words, what the nominal is here?
my attempt:
The nominal is the head part of "few" plus "of her friends". — Does this sound good in terms of linguistics?

If I add the word "very", the diagram would probably be the following:

It's easy to say what the NP is here: the NP is "very few of her friends".
But how to describe with words, what the DP is here?
my attempt:
The DP is "very" plus the determiner part of "few". — Does this sound good in terms of linguistics?

Update: I'm adding some diagrams which might be help.
a diagram from "CGELBank: CGEL as a Framework for English Syntax Annotation":



The branch from "Head: Nom" to "Determiner-Head: DP" goes strictly to the word "Head".

a diagram from the textbook "The Oxford Handbook of English Grammar" (the chapter "Modern and traditional descriptive approaches" relating to the CGEL), page 218:



The left branch from the NP and the left branch from the nominal converge above the middle of "Det-Head".

In CGEL, nominals by definition cannot include a determiner (Det). In a fused-head NP where the head is combined with and is inseparable from a determiner, there's no describing the nominal alone "with words."
In few of her friends, for example, we can't say the nominal is the entire phrase.
In very few of her friends, I believe CGEL would treat the entire very few as Det-Head in a diagram. Again, we can't describe in words what the nominal is.

You are confusing the syntactic function of 'Determiner' with the phrase label 'nominal'. And as you can clearly and unequivocally see from the CamGEL diagram, the phrase label "nominal" applies to the whole phrase. Determinatives can indeed anyhow appear in nominals. Consider "The few people who bothered to ask", for example. And, they can indeed, head them "Any two will do" etc etc.

@Araucaria-Him (1) I believe 'nominal' is also a syntactic function, as shown in the the second diagram on the same page, where Nom consists of Mod-Head: Adj second. (2) if few of her friends were a nominal and an NP at the same time, the NP and the nominal would exhibit singular branching, instead of the binary branching shown in the OP's diagram. (3) CGEL would analyze few in The few people who bothered to ask as not a determiner but a modifier. (cf. p394 [65ii]). Similarly, two in Any two will do would be a modifier-head in CGEL (though it's not as clearly written as few).

No, nominal's not a syntactic function. It is a phrase label. See this Wikipedia page in which the phrasal categories and syntactic function table and diagram were contributed by Brett Reynolds. You will see clearly that "nominal" appears in the phrasal category table and does not appear in comprehensive overview of the syntactic functions.

@Araucaria-Him OK. Thanks for pointing that out. But still, you'd have to respond to my (2) and (3).

Well, I wouldn't, I don't think  - mainly because it is a nominal and they do have binary branching (required to delineate the Head and Det functions within the NP). Regarding (3), which of your comments there disagrees with what I wrote? What I wrote was that determinatives can appear in and even head nominals.

@Araucaria-Him Re (3), you said, "Determinatives can indeed anyhow appear in nominals." But in the nominal few people who bothered to ask, few is a modifier (not a determinative), per CGEL. Moreover, if determinatives can belong in nominals, there's no reason to have 'nominal' as an intermediate phrase.

You're confusing determinative with Determiner. You need to have determinatives, nouns, nominals and NPs on one side and Determiners, Heads, Modifiers  and Complements on the other.

@Araucaria-Him No, I'm not. I know that determinatives, nouns, nominals and NPs are all syntactic categories, whereas Determiners, Heads, Modifiers and Complements represent grammatical functions. But that doesn't make your claim ("Determinatives can indeed anyhow appear in nominals.") correct. You gave me two examples to prove your point, but in neither does a determinative appear in a nominal.

Ok. In "The few people who bothered to ask" what is the nominal and what part of speech is few. Similarly in "Any two will do", what is the nominal and what part of speech is two?

@Araucaria-Him Per CGEL's p394 [65ii], in The few people who bothered to ask, the nominal is few people who bothered to ask and few is a determinative (part of speech) but functions as a modifier. Since Any two in Any two will do is also a fused NP, we can't specify the nominal in words. I suspect two is a determinative (part of speech) but functions as a modifier fused with an unstated noun denoting a class of a person or thing.

@Araucaria-Him Here, in the sentence "She earns [a lot more than I do]", BillJ said that the determiner-head is just the one word "more". So in "very few of her friends", he would also probably say that the determiner-head is just the one word "few", not "very few".

@Araucaria-Him The textbook "A Student's Introduction to English Grammar", 2022, page 133: The Fused-Head Construction: In a few cases the lexical head of an NP and a dependent of that head (usually the determiner or an internal modifier) are combined in a single word. That is, one word functions both as the determiner and the head, or as a modifier and the head, at the same time. We call this the fused-head construction. The textbook uses the formulations "a single word" and "one word". Does it mean that in "very few of her friends", the determiner-head is "few" (not "very few") ?

@Loviii Although BillJ tries to follow CGEL to a T, I find his comments/answers not always in line with CGEL. // Re "A Student's Introduction to English Grammar", its use of "a single word" or "one word" I find very unfortunate. CGEL doesn't limit a fused head to a single word. In fact, it has this example While Kim had lots of books, Pat had [very few]. on page 411, where the entire very few is underlined to indicate the fused head. Also, on page 415, they have I’d better take you to [the doctor’s], where the entire  the doctor’s is underlined to indicate the fused head. (Cont'd.)

@Loviii If the single word doctor’s (without the) were the fused head, the would have to determine doctor’s surgery, which is nonsensical.

@JK2 In you first comment you said"I know that determinatives, nouns, nominals and NPs are all syntactic categories, whereas Determiners, Heads, Modifiers and Complements represent grammatical functions. But that doesn't make your claim ("Determinatives can indeed anyhow appear in nominals.") correct. You gave me two examples to prove your point, but in neither does a determinative appear in a nominal". Then you said "In The few people who bothered to ask, the nominal is few people who bothered to ask and few is a determinative". Nominal in any two is two, a determinative.

@Loviii JK2 It's a small error that they accidentally repeat in kind in a few places. In their defence, they might well say that fused-head NPs are usually one word, which is how they characterise them and that the fact that they call such NPs fused head NPs does not rule out fused head NPs being headed by phrases. I say repeated because they say elsewhere that phrases are headed by words, but then go on to show phrases headed by phrases -a case in point being noun phrases, of course. Anyhow, you really don't need to think about thus ver hard. In "Very few people came", ...

@Loviii JK2 (cont), the Subject is Very few people. It's an NP. The Head of the NP is the nominal people, which is headed by the noun people. The Determiner is Very few, which is a determinative phrase. The Head the phrase  is the determinative few and its dependent is the Modifier realised by the adverb very. Now, if we leave out people and have Very few came, we now have a fused Determiner-Head NP functioning as Subject. Notice that both Determiner and Head are syntactic functions.  ... (2/3)

@Loviii JK2 And the Determiner function is being carried out by the same phrase that carried it out in "Very few people came".  That phrase is also carrying out the Head (i.e. nominal) function, but for our purposes that's a red herring. Notice that what's part of the Determiner is not negotiable, just like which words are part of the Subject is not negotiable. We can't make the Determiner just one word because we'd like to! Similarly for "the doctor's". The full phrase is something like "the doctor's surgery", where the Determiner is realised by the genitive NP "the doctor's". ...

@Loviii JK2 You can't make the Determiner shorter than this just because you would like it to be!

@Araucaria-Him First things first, I've realized I dropped the ball. When you earlier said: Determinatives can indeed anyhow appear in nominals. Consider "The few people who bothered to ask", for example. And, they can indeed, head them "Any two will do" etc etc., you were right about the determinatives few and two appearing in the respective nominals few people who bothered to ask and two. So I was wrong when I said, "You gave me two examples to prove your point, but in neither does a determinative appear in a nominal." Sorry about the confusion. (Cont'd.)

@Araucaria-Him But your claim that determinatives can appear in nominals, albeit correct, is not a relevant comment to my answer, where I mentioned not "determinatives" (POS) but "determiner" (function). In fact, the term nominal is defined to exclude not the determinative (POS) but the determiner (function). And in OP's example few of her friends, the whole of the word few cannot be included in the nominal, not because it's a determinative (POS) but because it's a determiner (function). So, your earlier claim that determinatives can appear in nominals is a red herring.

@Araucaria-Him CGEL, page 415: "I’d better take you to [the doctor’s]." - by your logic, the statement that "the doctor's" is a nominal here is correct. But isn't it odd that a nominal can begin with "the"?

@Loviii Araucaria-Him's logic is that since a nominal is the head of an NP, a determiner-head in a fused-head NP has to be a nominal. At first blush, this may sound logical, but it contradicts the fact that a nominal by definition excludes a determiner. A Student's Introduction to English Grammar (2022) states this in section 5.1.1: "In an NP like the guy who
fainted or a young woman, the nominal excludes the determiner, in the same way that, in a clause, the VP excludes the subject." Note how weird OP's tree diagram is. They need to remove the node Head: Nom and its two branches.

@Loviii Yes, but that's because all fused Determiner-Head NPs look like Determiners! (i.e. they're all weird).

@JK2 Loviii Where does this "by definition" bit come from? (1) ASIEG explain to the novice student that the Determiner and Head of the NP are separate phrases within the NP (out of which only the Head is mandatory). This is necessary because all the other XPs (or rather, all of the other XPs that aren't called clauses) can be built out of a single word, X. NP's are different because they are not directly headed by nouns and, instead, are headed by a phrase which, in turn, typically, has noun as its Head. A phrase which directly has a noun as its head is a nominal.

@JK2 loviii It's important for Ss to understand that unlike verb, adjective, adverb, preposition or determinative phrases, so-called noun phrases are not built around a single head word but around a head phrase, and may include dependents of that phrase. By highlighting the separate internal functions of Determiner and Head within the NP, ASIEG is just pointing out this structure to Ss. (2) In a fused Determiner-Head NP, however,  both functions are carried out by a single phrase. (3) NB - This is not my analysis, it's the CamGEL one. It's not what I believe.

@Araucaria-Him No, you're reading CGEL incorrectly. In OP's first diagram, the left branch of the node Head: Nom is connected to only the "Head" part of the Det-Head, not to the entire Det-Head. This is clearly shown in a 2022 paper titled "CGELBank: CGEL as a framework for English syntax annotation". In the first diagram on the first page, see how which is drawn. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.00394

@JK2 Loviii  No. You're mistaking an expository nicety to facilitate an understanding of the grammatical relations (i.e. syntactic functions) with some kind of pseudo-division of the phrases involved. If you look at the Subject part of in Fig. 1  and read also §3.2.2 you'll realise that while there's a doubling up of the functions realised by a single phrase in the Pre-Nucleus there, the structure in terms of phrases is crystal clear and unequivocal: NP-->Nom-->DP-->D. Now, the authors' emails are on the doc. If you disagree, feel free to seek clarification from them.

@JK2 Thank you for the link. I added the diagram from it to the original post. Also I added one more diagram which is drawn another way.

@JK2 Or you could just ping Brett Reynolds here under one of his posts and ask him.

@Araucaria-Him The "expository nicety" clearly explains that if you carefully look into it, only the Head part of the Determiner-Head is the sister of Head: Nom, which isn't some "pseudo-division" of the phrase. Also, why would you want me to look at the Subject part (Liz) of Fig. 1, which doesn't tell us anything about a fused-head NP? And the paper doesn't have §3.2.2. // BTW, do you agree that your earlier claim that determinatives can appear in nominals is a red herring? I'm asking because you've not responded to it.

@JK2 The point I was making in my original comment is that your post seemed to be confusing phrase and function quite generally. You backed this up by stating in comments that 'nominal' was a type of syntactic function (I'm not unsympathetic to that misunderstanding), and later  that determinatives could not appear in nominals. However, the reason I put it in the comments is so that readers would be aware (or you could change your post). Either way, it's an essential point that functions and phrases need to be kept separate and have quite different restrictions etc (The point of the comment)

@JK2 You're not going to persuade me that the nominal is not the phrase few of her friends. Mainly because I'm certain that's what it is and also how it's described in the diagram. However, if you want vindication of your claims, as stated, you could just ask Brett Reynolds here (I'm not saying that he'll have the time or inclination to answer, but he often does respond to posts and comments about CGEL and ASIEG). An answer from him would clear it up.

@Araucaria-Him If I had to ask someone, I'd rather ask GKP himself about it. He's been always very responsive and clear. And he's never been shy about admitting that CGEL is not perfect at all. // I'll make the question simpler. A nominal is an NP minus any determiner. Then, how can the nominal few of her friends include the determiner few?

@JK2 He's the author of the diagram that you say puts it very clearly. But, anyhow, feel free to ask whoever you want! You already have my interpretation of the CGEL grammar, including NPs,nominals, determinatives Heads and Determiners etc.

@Loviii In "The Oxford Handbook of English Grammar", I suspect that the diagrams are made simpler. I don't think they intended the diagram to be any different than CGEL's.

@Araucaria-Him No, you haven't answered THE question yet. How can the nominal few of her friends include the determiner few?

@JK2 We can come up with a logic for Araucaria's opinion. For example, it can be based on the fact that determiners and determiner-heads are different functions. That is, when a nominal includes a determiner-head, that doesn't mean this nominal includes a determiner.

@Loviii That logic flies in the face of the very definition of a fused head of a determiner and a head. So it's not even a logic. It's simply making a baseless exception.
